# Differential Equations - ODEINT

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-methods

I have to solve two differential equations by ODEINT in Python, the equations:

```
y''(t) = (l*q)/a * (1/y(p) * [1 - z'(p)*u]
z''(t) = a * (1/y(p) * y'(p)*u
```

So I was told to make:

```
y1=y
y2=y'
z1=z
z2=z'
```

and

```
y1' = y2
y2' = y'' = (l*q)/a * (1/y(p) * [1 - z'(p)*u]
z1' = z2
z2' = z''(t) = a * (1/y(p) * y'(p)*u
```

and now I have to solve these 4 equations. `l`, `q`, `a`, `u` are known.

I tried something like this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def rownanie(y, t, l, q, a, u):
    y1, y2, z1, z2 = y
    dydt = [y2, ((l*q)/a)*(1/y1)*(1-z2*u), z2, (a*y2*u)/y1]
    return dydt

l = 1
q = 1
a = 10
u = 0.25

y0 = 0
z0 = 0
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
sol = odeint(rownanie, y0, z0, t, args=(l,q,a,u))
print(sol)
```

Need help with this

Comment: "Need help with this" - could you be more specific? What is the output? What's wrong with it, how should it look like?

Comment: If you have an error, please post full traceback. If the results are not good, show what you get and how it is different from what you expected to get. Please, note that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: I think your problem is how you pass your initial value to the solver. The signature of `odeint` is `scipy.integrate.odeint(func, y0, t, args=(), ...)`, where `y0` includes all initial values (in your case 4), so the line should be something like `sol = odeint(rownanie, [y10, y20, z10, z20], t, args=(l,q,a,u))`, where `y10`, `y20`, `z10` and `z20` are the respective initial values.

Comment: Is there some significance behind the different arguments in your first equations? On the left side the second derivatives are evaluated at `t`, while on the right side the argument for the functions and first derivatives is `p`.

Comment: You haven't stated what does not work.  How can we help?  Please say what specifically is breaking down.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), you'll see `odeint`

> Solves the initial value problem for stiff or non-stiff systems of first order ode-s:
>
> dy/dt = func(y, t, ...)  [or func(t, y, ...)]
>
> where y can be a vector

This conversion is a standard mathematical way of transforming a second order ODE into a first order vector ODE.

You therefore create a new vector variable (I'll call it Y to avoid confusion), consisting of the vector `Y = [y, y_prime, z, z_prime]`: Your implementation of the function is correct.

Also note that in order to be solved numerically you need to specify the initial conditions of all the vector, in this case y0, z0, y'0 and z'0. As Thomas pointed out, you need to specify these values as the initial value of the vector when you call `odeint`.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def rownanie(Y, t, l, q, a, u):
    y1, y2, z1, z2 = Y
    dydt = [y2, ((l*q)/a)*(1/y1)*(1-z2*u), z2, (a*y2*u)/y1]
    return dydt

l = 1
q = 1
a = 10
u = 0.25

y0 = 0
z0 = 0
y0_prime, z0_prime = 0, 0  # you need to specify a value for these too
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
sol = odeint(rownanie, [y0, y0_prime, z0, z0_prime], t, args=(l,q,a,u))
print(sol)
```